# Why does my javascript function returns only first item of an array ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, scripting, frontend, web-frontend

I am a newbie to Javascript and trying my hands on it.

I wrote 2 functions.

The 1st function returns an array of digits and 2nd one loops through it and sums up the array but instead of that, it returns me the first item of an array only. Why ?

```
function addWorth()
    { 


        var table1= document.getElementById("tableNetWorths");

        var rowCount1= table1.rows.length;

        //var row1= table1.insertRow(rowCount1);


        var arr= [];


       for(var count = 0; count < rowCount1; count++)
       {    
            arr.push(table1.rows[count].cells[1].innerHTML);          
       }


       arr.shift();
       return arr;

    } 

    function showWorthSum()
    {
        var returnedArr= [];

        returnedArr.push(addWorth());

         totalWorth= 0;

        var arrCount= returnedArr.length;

        for(var count = 0; count < arrCount; count++)
        {    
             totalWorth= parseInt(totalWorth)+ parseInt(returnedArr[count]); 

        }

        return parseInt(totalWorth);
    }
```

button:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.write(showWorthSum())" type="button">Show Sum</button>
```

array:

100,200,344,22,122,99

Comment: Can you show some of your table HTML ?

Comment: @Covert I think what you want is var returnedArr = addWorth()

Comment: @hack3rfx thanks but I didn't get the reason behind it? Why would an array variable fail?

Comment: @Covert your addWorth function is returning an array.  You were adding that array, to another array.  What you want to do, is assign it, not "push" it.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the issue:

```
var returnedArr = addWorth();
```

Comment: `[[100,200,344,...]]` vs `[100,200,344,...]`

Comment: If you push, you will have an array with one element. The element itself will have a value of the return array. And you do not need that as you loop the return array elements.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you put a more extensive explanation into your answer.

Comment: @SamAxe but still [[100,200,344,...]] it has my elements in it, it should have added or had shown none, why would it show me 100 only  ?

Comment: If you still want to push then `var arrCount= returnedArr[0].length;` and `parseInt(returnedArr[0][count])`

Comment: @Covert: because `parseInt` needs a single int to operate on.. and you are passing it an array of ints.  Technically you should be passing it a string.. but whatever.

Comment: It would be the best to have `parseInt`  in the `addWorth` function in line `arr.push(parseInt(table1.rows[count].cells[1].innerHTML));`